# Templating Issue in flask/python

Tags: python, html, templates, flask, django-templates

As i follow a youtube tutorial on using flask and python to create a website , ive come across an error that has stumped me for hours.

For whatever reason , this line of code is not being interpreted properly by the platform and is yielding a "template not found" error when the site is launched.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2SkS.png)

the error upon running is shown below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n8o5.png)

another case of the django keyword {% %} not being recognized by the system.(line 18)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUfBn.png)

here is a link to the youtube video i am following. (ive linked it to the timestamp (36:00) in which home.html is created)

https://youtu.be/dam0GPOAvVI?t=2163

Tried downloading django through terminal , updated python path.

Comment: Please post the code as text not screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a base.html template. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/templateinheritance/
Example, base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">FSMA</a>
   </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="/show">Show</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </nav>
 <!--base template with jinja2-->
 {% block body %} {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

When you have your base you can extend:
Example, sample.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}FSMA{% endblock %} {% block body %}
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Flask show var data</h1>
  <p>{{ data }}</p>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

It seems that you are missing -{% endblock %}- in your first picture.

method call:

```
@app.route('/show')
def simple_show_data():
    data = "From Python"
    return render_template("sample.html", data=data)
```